How can I Get Values If Google Login Success?
In this 2nd example of google authentication: "Building a button with a custom graphic", I´m tryin to get values from auth with google (using exactly code in my domain), but when user make login, I always are receiving the error: "pop_up_closed_by_user" and the callback never run "function(googleUser){".
What´s the problem?
I would appreciate your help!
  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
        document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
              googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
        },
        function(error) {
            alert('success but:'+JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
  }


I just insert my CLIENT_ID in the [client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com' ]

It looks like you are using deprecated library. You should use the new Sign in with Google library instead.

Thanks hermz, my signin is ok now. My problem is to personalize my butto. I can´t using the google sugestion.

Can you provide more context on why you can't use the Google suggestion?

Hi friend Hermz, if you can? Thx for help... I need to resolv this:

access the page https://art-brazil.com/mob/start/
click in the profile icon in the top-right
click in the personal button  in the bottom
Look that: the button is redirecting to 2nd page with standard button. I don’t want this, i´d like that, when you click in my button, that the google alternatives it can show in the pop-up.


to see the download https://art-brazil.com/mob/start/head.txt

My problem is not to connect using google api auth2.0, the problem is that I can´t resize the google standard button.

I want to resize the google standard button to width="913" height="207", because it´s a mobile system.
